# Vue.js $emit arguments not rendering a dynamic component?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

What I'm trying to achieve:

I'm attempting to add a number of different component block types to the parent App.vue component on a click event from within a child of App.vue, using the `$emit` process and dynamic components.

What I have thus far:

Child component (ButtonSidebar.vue):

```
<template>
  <div>
    <b-button class="btn-circle absolute-float-tight text-dark" v-on:click="reveal=!reveal">
      <font-awesome-icon v-if="!reveal" :icon="faPlusIcon" />
      <font-awesome-icon v-if="reveal" :icon="faMinusIcon" />
    </b-button>
    <transition name="custom-classes-transition" enter-active-class="animated bounceInDown" leave-active-class="animated bounceOutRight">
      <div v-if="reveal" class="absolute-float-reveal">
        <b-button class="btn-circle text-dark" v-on:click="addCodeBlock"><font-awesome-icon :icon="faCodeIcon" /></b-button>
      </div>
    </transition>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import FontAwesomeIcon from '@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome'
import faPlus from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-pro-regular/faPlus'
import faMinus from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-pro-regular/faMinus'
import faCode from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-pro-regular/faCode'

export default {
  name: 'ButtonSidebar',
  computed: {
    faPlusIcon () {
      return faPlus
    },
    faMinusIcon () {
      return faMinus
    },
    faCodeIcon () {
      return faCode
    }
  },
  components: {
    FontAwesomeIcon
  },
  data () {
    return {
      reveal: false
    }
  },
  methods: {
    addCodeBlock () {
      this.$emit('addPageBlock', 'CodeBlock')
    },
    addQuoteBlock () {
      this.$emit('addPageBlock', 'QuoteBlock')
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Parent component (App.vue):

```
<template>
  <div id="app" class="container">

    <ButtonSidebar @add="addPageBlock"/>

    <div id="pageBlocks" ref="container">
      <component v-for="pageBlock in pageBlocks" v-bind:is="pageBlock.component" v-bind:key="pageBlock.id"></component>
    </div>

  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Vue from 'vue'
import BootstrapVue from 'bootstrap-vue'

import ButtonSidebar from './components/modules/ButtonSidebar'
import CodeBlock from './components/modules/CodeBlock'

import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'
import 'bootstrap-vue/dist/bootstrap-vue.css'

Vue.use(BootstrapVue)

export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: {
    AddTitle,
    AddSubTitle,
    ButtonSidebar,
    CodeBlock
  },
  data () {
    return {
      pageBlocks: []
    }
  },
  methods: {
    addPageBlock (componentName) {
      this.pageBlocks.push({ component: componentName })
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

And for prosperity, my basic CodeBlock component:

```
<template>
  <div :class="type">
    THIS IS A CODE BLOCK!!
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'CodeBlock',
  props: [ 'type' ]
}
</script>
```

For some reason, the v-on:click:"addCodeBlock" event is working, but the subsequent firing of the emit to the parent component is not working ... I've tried to `console.log` but nothing is going through...can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: ButtonSideBar is emitting `addPageBlock` but App is listening for `add`, `@add="addPageBlock"`. Also, don't use camelCased event names. Use kebab-case, `add-page-block`.

Comment: @Bert - got it in one, so it is the bind not the method, of course. Silly when it's spelled out for you! Thank you :)

Comment: @Bert just curious why I've to avoid camelCased event names?

Comment: @Brissy This is covered now [in the documentation](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html#Event-Names). They explain it better than I can in a comment :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ButtonSidebar emits an `addCodeBlock` event but here

```
<ButtonSidebar @add="addPageBlock"/>
```

The parent is listening for an `add` event.

Try changing it like so:

```
<ButtonSidebar @addCodeBlock="addPageBlock"/>
```

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thanks Christophe